# Android manifest error after adding the google_maps_api key

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3, maps

I added  to my android manifest file and it came up with errors at android:icon, android:launchMode, android:theme and others. How do I resolve this?

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.diabetes">
   <application
        android:label="diabetes"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="************"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What are the error message you get? It looks exactly like my working manifest file with google maps api. Only difference is I also have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this? I'm running into it now.